# Plotting a point in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

In applet we have a drawline function.
i want to plot a point in form. i tried to view code but can't. [drawline plots a series of points
]

```
public abstract void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
```

is it possible to do something like that in swing or applet?

**how to plot a single point in java forms?**

Comment: Please post your code & explain what isnt working

Comment: what's wrong with fillCircle?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: *"..in swing or applet?"*  That's an illogical 'or'.  Swing has `JFrame` *and* `JApplet` while the AWT equivalents are `Frame` and `Applet`.  Use Swing rather than AWT (better), and `JFrame` rather that `JApplet` (easier).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `drawRect` for example. If you wish to plot a lot of single pixels, you could use an array and `BufferedImage`, but that's a bit more advanced rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot a single point by calling `drawLine` with the same start and end points.

```
g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
```

Another way is filling a 1-by-1 rectangle.

```
g.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
```

Plotting single pixels is terribly inefficient though. If you want to draw an entire image you should use a `BufferedImage` instead. To set pixels you would use the [`setRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot a single point just calling setRGB in BufferedImage.

```
BufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
```

Comment: how to initialize bufferedimage? i'm beginner.

Comment: BufferedImage buf = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

if you want to load an image from disk.

 BufferedImage buf = ImageIO.read(new File(pathname));

Comment: `BufferedImage buf = ImageIO.read(new File(pathname));`  Not in a (sand-boxed) applet..